# Texture Paint Stencil Transparency + Transform

Tags: texture-painting

Hi I'm trying to get stenciling to work for texture painting.

But when loading up the image that'll be used for stenciling the image comes out very transparent. Additionally none of the transformation macros seem to apply to the stencil; which I had confirmed in settings are set properly.

[image]

Additionally, when loading up a stencil, it seems to appear transparent making it difficult to use it properly.

[image]

I updated to the latest version of Blender - v2.93.6 - to try and see if it was a bug, but the issue still persisted even with the update.

I haven't found any solutions online for this, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For the stencil opacity, have you tried to tweak the Texture Opacity value in the N panel > Tool >Brush Settings  Cursor?

Comment: I did, which seems to make it more visible. However, it still seems to have a shadow effect, even after adjusting the Brush Cursor Settings.